# Долго грузятся странички сайта

Tags: загрузка, веб-сервер, apache2

Здравствуйте. Проблема заключается в следующем: сменил я недавно провайдера, настроил VPS и тут у меня стали очень долго грузиться странички и даже видео, css файлы, картинки по прямым ссылкам. Написал я в поддержку, мне ответили, что всё работает нормально, посоветовали оптимизировать БД и прочее, хотя я сомневаюсь, что видео по прямой ссылке открывается долго отнюдь не из-за не оптимизированной БД или апача. Но я заметил, что такое происходит в основном тогда, когда на сайте больше 15-20 пользователей. Тормоза происходят не всегда, а периодически. В чём проблема? Мой косяк или провайдера? на предыдущих серверах всё работало отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте nginx перед apache, если этого ещё не сделано. Апач вообще очень плохо держит серьёзную нагрузку. Вполне возможно что одного этого будет достаточно.